# PHPUnit test can't find factory

Tags: laravel, phpunit, phpstorm

I have a unit test that uses a `JobFactory` and `ClientFactory`.

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class JobTest extends TestCase
{
    /** @test */
    function can_display_job_details()
    {
        $job = create('App\Job', [
            'job-number' => 9999,
            'site' => 'Homeville',
            'client_id' => function(){
                return create('App\Client', [
                    'name' => 'ACME'
                ])->id;
            },

        ]);

        $details = $job->job_details;

        $this->assertEquals('EPS-9999-Homeville-RES', $details);

    }
}
```

When I run the test I get this error

```
InvalidArgumentException : Unable to locate factory with name [default] [App\Job].
```

I use the factory App\Job (JobFactory) in my feature test with no issues.
I use PhpStorm's built in PHPUnit testing function.

I run create and make through a little test helper

```
<?php

function create($class, $attributes = [], $times = null)
{
    return factory($class, $times)->create($attributes);
}

function make($class, $attributes = [], $times = null)
{
    return factory($class, $times)->make($attributes);
}
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong but I can't seem to get to the bottom of it.
Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are extending the wrong `TestCase` class.

Change:

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
```

to:

```
use Tests\TestCase;
```

[Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/testing#creating-and-running-tests) you can find an example.